# Google Sheets Email Multi-able Cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I add another auto email reply based on the additional value "Declined" in the cell and then sent out a different message "Your Request was Declined please submit with correct details".
Please help

```
    function sendEmail(e) {
    var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    if (ss.getName() !== 'Form Responses 1' || e.range.columnStart !== 22 || 
    e.value !== 'Completed') return;
    var values = ss.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 2, 1, 7)
    .getValues()[0];
    var headers = ss.getRange(1, 2, 3, 7)
    .getValues()[0];
    var subject = "New Vendor Request Completed";
    var email = values[0];
    var cols = [1, 2, 3];
    var body = "Hi,\n\n We are please to let you know that the vendor that you have requested has been added to the system of you request. Please read the details below.\n\n"; //add more text if you want to..
    for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (cols.indexOf(i) === -1) continue;
    body += headers[i] + ": " + values[i] + "\n"
    }
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body)
```

Comment: If you could share your sheet, or a dummy copy with at least the column headers, that would help.  We don't know what cell "Declined" would be in... see  [ask].  But a quick way would be to create a duplicate of this function and alter the appropriate lines.

Comment: Ron, Its the same cell as the "Completed" is looking at.

Comment: I tried to create a duplicate of this function, but when I did the first one would not work. (Only the last one I saved.)

Comment: Would you be able to share a copy of the spreadsheet?

Comment: Here a copy of the sheet   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o77ggMUvHRoBNfifw4G5W_hIT3MVT3jHqSXJMSkQFow/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The drop down is on column "V"  the 2 options which would send out the email on Completed or Declined.

Answer (score 0):

I put this together mainly for my own practice.  I hope it does what you want.

I separated out the data gathering portion from the email portion, then created two different email functions, called by if statements looking for the `Completed` or `Declined` edit.

```
function sendEmail(e) {
  var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (ss.getName() !== 'Form Responses 1' || e.range.columnStart !== 22) return;
  var values = ss.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 2, 1, 7)
    .getValues()[0];
  var headers = ss.getRange(1, 2, 3, 7)
    .getValues()[0];
  if ( e.value == 'Completed') {
   completed(values, headers);
   }
  else if ( e.value == 'Declined') {
   declined(values, headers);
   }
  }


function completed(values, headers) {
  var subject = "New Vendor Request Completed";
  var email = values[0];
  var cols = [1, 2, 3];
  var body = "Hi,\n\n We are please to let you know that the vendor that you have requested has been added to the system of you request. Please read the details below.\n\n"; //add more text if you want to..
  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (cols.indexOf(i) === -1) continue;
      body += headers[i] + ": " + values[i] + "\n"
    }
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body)
  }

function declined(values, headers) {
  var subject = "New Vendor Request Declined";
  var email = values[0];
  var cols = [1, 2, 3];
  var body = "Hi,\n\n Unfortunately, the vendor that you have requested has not been added to the system of you request. Please read the details below.\n\n"; //add more text if you want to..
  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (cols.indexOf(i) === -1) continue;
     body += headers[i] + ": " + values[i] + "\n"
    }
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body)
  }
```

Let me know if this doesn't do what you need.